# Application failed codesign verification. (-19011)

Tags: iphone, xcode, code-signing

For a few days Im being stuck at this problem, I've tried to delete/clean all the keys/certification and redownload them, I've tried to remove all provision profiles and revoke them and renew them. But every time I'm getting this problem.

Im running the latest Xcode, 4.3.2.

> warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was
>   invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with
>   an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)"
>
> Validate
>   /Users/jimmylind91/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JagHarAldrig-bkpyqdmptyxcntauxwsbrsqbmlji/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JagHarAldrig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/JagHarAldrig.app
>       cd "/Users/jimmylind91/Documents/xCode/Jag Har Aldrig"
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       setenv PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.application
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/Validation
>   /Users/jimmylind91/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JagHarAldrig-bkpyqdmptyxcntauxwsbrsqbmlji/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JagHarAldrig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/JagHarAldrig.app
>
> warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was
>   invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with
>   an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)
>   Executable=/Users/jimmylind91/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JagHarAldrig-bkpyqdmptyxcntauxwsbrsqbmlji/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JagHarAldrig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/JagHarAldrig.app/JagHarAldrig
>   codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: using Apple CA for profile evaluation
>   /Users/jimmylind91/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JagHarAldrig-bkpyqdmptyxcntauxwsbrsqbmlji/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JagHarAldrig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/JagHarAldrig.app:
>   valid on disk
>   /Users/jimmylind91/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JagHarAldrig-bkpyqdmptyxcntauxwsbrsqbmlji/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/JagHarAldrig/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/JagHarAldrig.app:
>   satisfies its Designated Requirement test-requirement: code failed to
>   satisfy specified code requirement(s) codesign_wrapper-0.7.10: failed
>   to execute codesign(1)
>    - (null)

Comment: So are you building for the app store, ad hoc, or just for development? Let us know what configuration you are building, and what the code sign section in your build settings reads. In your app id in iOS provisioning portal, did you select iCloud support? If so you will need an Entitlements File for iCloud: See here: [iCloud programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure that you have setup the distribution provisioning profile under your provisioning portal!

create new profile....download its and set it up...

that will fix your problem i hope.
greats from switzerland
Oliver

Answer (score 18):

I too got the "Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate. (-19011)".  I recently updated to Xcode 4.5.1.

In my case the solution was to go to my target's build settings and under "Build Options" change the "Validate Build Product" settings.  I changed "Debug" from "Yes" to "No".

Comment: I had Ad hoc and Release set to yes and when I changed them all to no, the warning dissapeared.

Answer (score 3):

Just read on sdk forums it has to do with length of product name.

"All that I needed to do to sort this out was change the PRODUCT NAME in Build Settings to something shorter. Also make sure that in the info.plist the bundle name either reads from ProductName or is also short – it can be 3 characters since the bundle display name is the one that appears to users!" - Zuningo from sdk forum.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot. It was in fact the length of the build configuration that triggered the error. After shortening the build configuration name everything worked!

Comment: I don't see why this got downvoted, it certainly worked for me. The name of my app was too long and when I shortened it, the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading Distribution Certificate (not the provisioning certificate) from iOS Provisioning Portal and installing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have three configurations: Debug; Release; Distribution. I had such problem and didn't understand what to do. I used a decision from user [dre1138](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743966/dre1138) and modernized it some. In TARGETS->myapp->Build Options->Validate Built Product I turned off Debug and Release in "No" and turn on Distribution in "Yes". Problem was decided.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do two things:

1. Delete expired certificates in Keychain Access. By default they are not shown, you have to enable it in the menu.
2. Tick the checkbox "Entitlements [x] Use Entitlements File: " on the "Summary" Tab of the Target properties.